# How to input the echo value to complete the query?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Help pls. I just want to complete the query but I don't know how to put the echo value `show tables from (echo value which is the database)`.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['database'])){

    echo $_POST['database'];

    $qry = "show tables from ";    
    $res = mysqli_query($link,$qry);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
         echo $row[0]."<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: When you echo $row inside the while loop, you use the column name as the array index, not a number, eg $row["column_name"].  See http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php for some examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can easily complete your query with input values see below code :

```html
<?php
 if (isset($_POST['database'])){

 echo $_POST['database'];

 $qry = "show tables from " . $_POST['database'];    
 $res = mysqli_query($link,$qry);

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
  echo $row[0]."<br>";
  }
  }
```

but take a look at sql injections hack if this function is internal function its ok but if you get your database name from an external client you should complete your query with something like below codes :

```html
in PDO :

$query = "SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE enabled = 1 AND id = :id";
$stmnt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmnt->execute(array(':id' => $_POST['id']));
```

Comment: its not working sir.

Comment: could you echo your query ? using this --> die(json_encode($qry)); and send me the result

Comment: yes it says "show tables from (database) I think the problem is the other quotation mark is in the next row of the page.

Comment: oh yeah i get it. cuz i use <br> on my first code.. thanks.

Comment: ok edit your while echo to this and send the result : echo json_encode($row)."<br>";